# Visual Studio Code - erb and html together

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, erb

I have a .erb
Which means that I have HTML syntax inline.

File association for .erb is .erb using Ruby Extension and Simple Ruby Extension, I also have the HTML Snippets extension installed

What I want is to provide HTML snippets within the .erb file - but it seems I can only have one of the other.

HTML Snippets gives if I add *.erb: "html" then I lose the .erb snippets

```
"files.associations": {
        // extension name : html
        "*.ejs": "html",
        "*.js": "html"
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub issue may help you out: [HTML snippets in other languages](https://github.com/abusaidm/html-snippets/issues/27#issuecomment-282512411). According to this link, you'll need to add some extra lines to the `package.json` file that comes with the snippet extension.